# hteaccess: Pretty url by htaccess showing 404 error

Tags: .htaccess

I am beginner in codding. I want make url pretty. I search this question on google then i found i have to use .htaccess. I tried htaccess code.

Here is my URL looklike
**website.com/project-details.php?Residential/The-Serenas/1**

I want to make url like **website.com/Residential/The-Serenas/1**

I want to remove entire **"project-details.php?"** word from url by htaccess.

here is my .htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteBase /basename/ 





# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /project-details\.php\?([^\s&]+) [NC] 

RewriteRule ^ view/%1? [R=302,L] 



RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /project-details\?([^\s&]+) [NC] 

RewriteRule ^ view/%1? [R=302,L] 







# internally rewrites /view/ABC123 to project-details.php?ABC123 

RewriteRule ^view/([A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]+)$ project-details.php?$1 [L,NC,QSA] 





# PHP hiding rule 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Above htaccess code work and url replacce to **website.com/view/Residential/The-Serenas/1**

If i remove **view** from this line `RewriteRule ^ view/%1? [R=302,L]`.

Then page goes to 404 error. If i dont remove view then code worked but **view** show on url.
I dont want to show anything on url only remove "project-details.php?" this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule is to check the request uri whether is `/project-details.php` and any query string follow behind, and redirect user to the uri that matches the query string. `%1` is the backreference and provide access to the grouped parts (in parentheses) of the pattern, in this case `([^\s&]+)`. For example, if uri `/project-details.php?Residential/The-Serenas/1` is requested, the user will be redirected to `/Residential/The-Serenas/1`.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /project-details\.php\?([^\s&]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]
```

This rule is to check if user requests existing file and directory, if not, then the uri is rewritten internally (only server knows the destination uri, user does not know this). For example, if uri `/Residential/The-Serenas/1` is requested, the server will rewrite the uri to `project-details.php?/Residential/The-Serenas/1`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]+)$ project-details.php?$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: 404 error page not showing if anyone write wrong url then page always redirect to project-details.php this page.